# 404 error with GitHub pages when trying to publish with GitHub

Tags: javascript, html, css, github-pages

I'm trying to host a page on GitHub pages, but I seem to be having some errors with it.
From what I understand, everything is where it should be, but I keep getting a 404 error when I try and access the page.

Link to the repo:
https://github.com/Karan-Ghatt/My-Portfolio

It should be active at:
https://karan-ghatt.github.io/My-Portfolio/

I would really appreciate if you could have a look and see if you can tell what's going on.
Much love people!

EDIT:
Thank you for your help, this turned out to be a naming error.

Answer (score 3):

Your `index.html` starts with a capital 'I', making it `Index.html`.

Your site is live at https://karan-ghatt.github.io/My-Portfolio/Index.html.

You can rename the `Index.html` to `index.html` so that the directory call catches it.

Comment: THANK YOU! Can't believe I didn't catch that! I will make sure to make sure my names match up across everything. I've managed to get it linked to the original GitHib pages link. I can't seem to get all the images to load. It manages to find the about image but nothing else, even though their in the same directory in the repo??

Comment: You're welcome!. Not sure why but one of your images is loading when it is coded as `<img src="./images/abremovals.png" style="width:100%" alt="">` while another is not loading when it's coded as `<img style="width:100%" alt="" src="/images/resume.png">`. You can see the second one is missing a period after `src="`. I'd try making those uniform.